# Macro Single Step, Error 3270

Tags: ms-access

Even though I'm new to access, things were progressing well, but I've hit the wall with a few issues.  I've inherited a split database with four pieces, a backend version, frontend version and two user versions in accde form.  The users wanted some changes, so I needed to add a few forms, modify a few forms, add a table and come up with the queries for the changes.  That work is complete and I was able to convert the new frontend accdb version to the user accde versions.   Some of the users are able to open the database, but some of the users are getting a Macro Single Step message with the following information;

Macro Name:  AutoExec

Action Name:  RunCode

Error Number:  3270

There's also a message about the backend location not being a valid path, but of course it is.

I'm wondering what the differences  would be between the users who are able to get in and those that aren't.  I've added the location to their trusted sites and I've changed their macro settings with no success.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks, Bill

Comment: If you want a specific answer, the macro code/screenshot would help. Common causes for differences between users include language settings (decimal separator, date settings), differences in installed requirements (when referencing libraries) and differences in the MS Access version (32 bit vs 64 bit).

Comment: Hi Erik,   Public Function GetUserInfo()

myLogin = ap_GetUserName()
myPos = GetPosition()
myName = GetName()

If myPos = 10 Then
    myID = DLookup("UserID", "SAUsers", "Login = '" & myLogin & "'")
    myDept = 0
    Else
    myID = DLookup("UserID", "tblEmployees", "Login = '" & myLogin & "'")
    myDept = DLookup("Department", "tblEmployees", "Login = '" & myLogin & "'")
End If

End Function

Comment: Well, that doesn't say a whole lot since the function is calling other user-defined functions (such as GetPosition and GetName). My best guess is one of those is doing things with database location or user name, and then resulting in errors because one of those is not what it expects. Try running your development DB on their system with them logged in at the location they would place the file to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Yeah, there's a cap on the number of characters in a comment, will try and list then separately...

Comment: Function ap_GetUserName() As Variant
   
   Dim strUserName As String
   Dim lngLength As Long
   Dim lngResult As Long

   '-- Set up the buffer
   strUserName = String$(255, 0)
   lngLength = 255

   '-- Make the call
   lngResult = wu_GetUserName(strUserName, lngLength)
   
   '-- Assign the value
   ap_GetUserName = Left(strUserName, InStr(1, strUserName, Chr(0)) - 1)
   
End Function

Comment: Public Function GetPosition() As Variant Dim UserName As String UserName = ap_GetUserName()
'Checks if user is in Service Analytics, otherwise gets value from Employees table If Not IsNull(DLookup("UserName", "SAUsers", "Active = True AND Login = '" & [UserName] & "'")) Then GetPosition = 10 Else If Not IsNull(DLookup("UserName", "tblEmployees", "Active = True AND Login = '" & [UserName] & "'")) Then GetPosition = DLookup  "Position", "tblEmployees", "Active = True AND Login = '" & [UserName] & "'") Else GetPosition = 0 MsgBox ("User not authorized")
    DoCmd.Quit End If End If End Function

Comment: Public Function GetName() As Variant

Dim UserName As String
UserName = ap_GetUserName()

'Checks if user is in Service Analytics, otherwise gets value from Employees table
If Not IsNull(DLookup("UserName", "SAUsers", "Active = True AND Login = '" & [UserName] & "'")) Then
GetName = DLookup("UserName", "SAUsers", "Login = '" & [UserName] & "'")
Else
GetName = DLookup("UserName", "tblEmployees", "Login = '" & [UserName] & "'")
End If

End Function